# Cordova iOS App is unable to fetch HTTP resources when App is launched in another country?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

We have a Cordova iOS app that we are beta testing using Test Flight.  The App ran (and still runs) fine when launched from iOS test devices based in the US.

We have a beta tester who ran the App just fine while in the US, but now they are in London and the App will not fetch HTTP resources anymore.  They have no problem loading the resource URL within iOS Safari.

I don't believe this is an access origin issue, as I have very permissive rules set:

```
<access origin="http://*"/>
<access origin="https://*"/>
```

Can anyone think of any reason such an App would fail to work while another country?  (Multiple different ISPs have been tested: WiFi at hotel, coffee shop, and roaming cellular.  All have the same results where Safari loads resources fine but App will not).

Comment: Is the device running iOS 9? Could it be App Transport Security because you're doing communication over HTTP?

Comment: @chedabob This was a great suggestion, thanks!  But I just checked my .plist file and have NSAppTransportSecurity -> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = YES